How to share both Pdf and text on whatsapp in single intent in android?
private void shareFileAndLinkViaIntent() {
Set selectedDispatches = mRetailerHistoryAdapter.getSelectedDispatchItems();
Set selectedOtherItems = mRetailerHistoryAdapter.getSelectedOtherItems();
    try {
        // Track events for sharing
        for (CustomerHistoryListBean item : selectedDispatches) {
            Utils.getInstance().eventTracking(this, "dispatch_share");
        }
        for (CustomerHistoryListBean item : selectedOtherItems) {
            Utils.getInstance().eventTracking(this, item.getActivity_type() + "_share");
        }

        StringBuilder shareText = new StringBuilder();

        // Add links and documents for dispatch transactions
        for (CustomerHistoryListBean dispatchItem : selectedDispatches) {
            String dispatchLink = getShareLink(dispatchItem);
            shareText.append(AppConstants.DEEP_LINK_TYPE.DISPATCH).append(": ").append(dispatchLink).append("\n\n");
        }

        // Add links for other transactions
        for (CustomerHistoryListBean otherItem : selectedOtherItems) {
            String otherLink = getShareLink(otherItem);
            String activityName = getActivityDeeplinkType(otherItem);
            shareText.append(activityName).append(": ").append(otherLink).append("\n\n");
        }

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

        if (!dispatchFilesUri.isEmpty()) {
            // Handle multiple files
            if (dispatchFilesUri.size() > 1) {
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, dispatchFilesUri);
            } else {
                // Single file
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setType("application/pdf");
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, dispatchFilesUri.get(0));
            }
        } else {
            // Text-only sharing
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        }

        // Add shared text
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText.toString());
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getString(R.string.share_link_ex)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

This code is working fine for gmail, but it is not working for whatsapp.
